# Country shapes for google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing few experiments using Google Maps and now I was taking a look to the circles.

My idea is to create a circle for each country in Europe and load the markers inside only when someone click on the circle.

I did it and works fine.

Now what I'd like to do is to create a shape of the countries and replace each circle.

I was looking at the polygons and it seems to be what I'm looking for but creating a good shape for each country takes a planty of time...

There is a Google Maps service that highlight the countries that you need? (Not Google Charts, I already took a look on it)

Or Exist something already builded to import easily with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundaries of the world countries are available in the [Natural Earth data set](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2011/02/natural-earth-vectors-in-cloud.html) and in a public FusionTable.

[Here is an example using that data to display French provinces](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=France)

Comment: I have one more question. Is it possible clicking on the oerlay to load from my server all markers inside that overlay? Do it return Bounds or something else?

Comment: The FusionTablesLayer object will not return bounds.  Point in polygon analysis is probably the subject of another question after you do some research.  You can compute the bounds of a polygon with the Google Maps API v3, but that will be a rectangle.