# Google map highlight boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Hi I am working on google map.I got struct with highlighting border of searched location.Can any one help me to find the Boundary points of **new google.maps.Polygon** to hightlight the searched address...

Comment: What kind of "searched location"? How are you doing the search? Are you looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831968/google-maps-single-country-boundary/11832316#11832316 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747487/country-shapes-for-google-maps/13749268#13749268

Comment: Please update your question with the requested information (and your code).

Comment: Sry for first time im using stackoverflow to ask question

Comment: and in the below link i have asked my question clearly                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368473/google-map-boundary-of-searched-location

Comment: please guide me to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

for google maps chech this [Embedding Maps into a Website](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/websitemaps.html) and [Google maps Api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)