# Google Map Boundary of searched Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I have used the following code to display the marker on the location I have dynamically searched for(code). Now I want to highlight the searched location boundary. (For instance, if I search 'Tokyo', it should mark the boundary of 'Tokyo'(chk [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrqLi.jpg) for reference).

```
var geocoder;

var map;

 function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

var mapOptions = {

    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng

}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}


function codeAddress() {

var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location

        });
    }

    else 

    {
        $('#noResults').html("Unsuccessful:" + status);

    }

});
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```